# JavaScript - check if this (current element) has a class ending with

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

To select input ending with `-top` I can sue the following:

`$("input[class$='-top'],input[class*='-top ']")`

But, how to check if this end with `-top`?

```
$('Input').keyup( function(){

 // How to check if $(this).prop('class') end with  "-top"

});
```

How to check if `$(this).prop('class') end with  "-top"`

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier just to use `.top` class and `$(".top")`. And replace `.something-top` with `.something.top`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `.is()`:

```
if ($(this).is('[class*=-top]')) { ... }
```

*edit* — substitute in the selector of your choice of course ...

Comment: You have to change the selector to `[class$=-top],[class*=-top ]`. Otherwise, `class="-top-not-ending"` also matches.

Comment: Ah right. Sorry; the main point was the `.is()` function itself.